# Concatenating every other array element

Tags: java

I am learning how to use Java 8 streams.  How can I do the following using streams instead of a for loop:

```
public static void clump(ArrayList strList)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        String newStr = "(" + strList.get(i) + " "
                + strList.get(i + 1) + ")";

        strList.set(i, newStr);
        strList.remove(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an `IntStream` between 0 and half the list's size, and multiply the elements by 2:

```
List<String> joined = 
    IntStream.range(0, strList.size() / 2)
        .mapToObj(i -> "(" + strList.get(2*i) + " "
                + strList.get(2*i + 1) + ")")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This puts the joined elements into a new list. To get rid of the un-joined elements from the original list, and prepend the joined elements, we can use a [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)), which is a mutable view of the list:

```
List<String> subList = strList.subList(0, strList.size() / 2 * 2);
subList.clear();
subList.addAll(joined);
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/CIpZik)

---

An alternative to the sublist stuff would be to handle the last element in the stream too:

```
List<String> joined = 
    IntStream.range(0, (1 + strList.size()) / 2)
        .mapToObj(i ->
            (2*i + 1) < strList.size()
                ? "(" + strList.get(2*i) + " " + strList.get(2*i + 1) + ")"
                : strList.get(2*i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/jDvtgA)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Andy Turner looks wonderful. Here I just provide alternative solution by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common).

```
List<String> strList = N.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
List<String> result = Stream.of(strList).split(2).map(e -> e.join(" ", "(", ")")).toList();
N.println(result); // [(a b), (c d)]

strList = N.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
result = Stream.of(strList).split(2).map(e -> e.join(" ", "(", ")")).toList();
N.println(result); // [(a b), (c d), (e)]
```